# Why navbar isnt rendering in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have been trying to figure out why my navbar in jsx isnt rendering properly in the DOM.
The div directly below it renders but whatever reason when I call the navbar "nav1" it does not render.
Maybe someone can see something wrong in my code.  Its probably obvious but I am new to react.

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>


    <script type="text/babel">
        // Obtain the root 
            const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
        // Create a ES6 class component    
            class nav1 extends React.Component { 
        // Use the render function to return JSX component      
            render() {
            return (
           
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li className="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        

        );
    }
}
         
// Create a function to wrap up your component
function App(){
  return(
  <div>
    <nav1 />
    <div className="container">
    <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
    <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>
  </div>
  )
}
            

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
rootElement
)
```

Comment: I think react components must be Capitalized so instead of `nav1` it should be `Nav1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hassan Azzam is right. When using JSX, custom react components must start with a capital letter. To cite the official docs:

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#:%7E:text=The%20first%20part%20of%20a,Foo%20must%20be%20in%20scope.)

So to resolve your issue rename your class from `nav1` to `Nav1`.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sbxk1g2o/7/

Comment: so simple but yes that fixed it.